# Non-Static method acting static?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

Trying to invoke a non-Static method in a class from my main class, made an instance of the main class, and try to run the method from a non-static method, but I still keep getting a "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error.

Main class looks like this;

```
public class WeatherController {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WeatherController mainController = new WeatherController();
        mainController.doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        WeatherObservation newObservation = new WeatherObservation("Whyalla", "28-02-17", 38, 0, 1.3, 1);
        WeatherObservation.printObservation(newObservation);  
        WeatherHistory newHistory = new WeatherHistory();   //Create new History Array
        newHistory.arrayAdd(newObservation);                //Add the Observation to it.

// These are the problem methods:
        WeatherHistory.arrayPrint(newHistory);
        WeatherObservation.setTemp(10);
     }
} // End Class
```

doStuff should be non-static, because I'm running it on an instance of mainController, right? But it can't call setTemp or arrayPrint.

Comment: Just because you have an instance of `WeatherController` doesn't mean you can call instance methods of `WeatherHistory` or `WeatherObservation` without an instance of those classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WeatherHistory.arrayPrint(newHistory);
WeatherObservation.setTemp(10);
```

These are static calls, replace them with below code :

```
newHistory.arrayPrint(newHistory);
newObservation.setTemp(10);
```

Comment: Or make them static, as `WeatherObservation.printObservation()` presumably is. Seems more useful than `newHistory.arrayPrint(newHistory)`.